# Eval compute is incomplete when own decidability is used in Coq

Tags: coq

The `Eval compute` command does not always evaluate to a simple expression.
Consider the code:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Peano_dec.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive I : Set := a : nat -> I | b : nat -> nat -> I.

Lemma I_eq_dec : forall x y : I, {x = y}+{x <> y}.
Proof.
  repeat decide equality.
Qed.
```

And, if I execute the following command:

```coq
Eval compute in (if (In_dec eq_nat_dec 10 [3;4;5]) then 1 else 2).
```

Coq tells me that the result is `2`. However, when I execute the following expression:

```coq
Eval compute in (if (In_dec I_eq_dec (a 2) [(a 1);(a 2)]) then 1 else 2).
```

I get a long expression where the In-predicate seems to be unfolded, but no result is given.

What do I have to change to obtain the answer `1` in the last `Eval compute` line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Coq there are two terminator commands for proof scripts: `Qed` and `Defined`. The difference between them is that the former creates *opaque* terms, which cannot be unfolded, even by `Eval compute`. The latter creates transparent terms, which can then be unfolded as usual. Thus, you just have to put `Defined` in the place of `Qed.`:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Peano_dec.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive I : Set := a : nat -> I | b : nat -> nat -> I.

Lemma I_eq_dec : forall x y : I, {x = y}+{x <> y}.
Proof.
  repeat decide equality.
Defined.

Eval compute in (if (In_dec I_eq_dec (a 2) [(a 1);(a 2)]) then 1 else 2).
```

I personally find the sumbool type `{A} + {B}` not very nice for expressing decidable propositions, precisely because proofs and computation are too tangled together; in particular, proofs affect how terms reduce. I find it better to follow the [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr) style, separate proofs and computation and relate them via a special predicate:

```
Inductive reflect (P : Prop) : bool -> Set :=
  | ReflectT of P : reflect P true
  | ReflectF of ~ P : reflect P false.
```

this gives a convenient way for saying that a boolean computation returns true iff some property is true. Ssreflect provides support for conveniently switching between the computational boolean view and the logical view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate your proofs, you need to make them transparent. You do that by finishing them with the `Defined` command. The `Qed` command makes them opaque, meaning it discards their computational content.