# Coq can't compute a well-founded function on Z, but it works on nat

Tags: recursion, coq, totality

I'm writing (for myself) an explanation of how to do well-founded recursion in Coq. (see i.e. the Coq'Art book, chapter 15.2).  First I made an example function based on `nat` and that worked fine, but then I did it again for `Z`, and when I use `Compute` to evaluate it, it doesn't reduce all the way down to a `Z` value.  Why?

Here is my example (I put the text inside comments so one can copy-paste the whole thing into your editor):

---

(* Test of well-founded recursion *)

(* TL;DR: To do well-founded recursion, 
   first create 'functional' and then 
   create the recursive function using
   Acc_iter, the iterator for accessible relations
*)

(* As an example, compute the sum of the series from 1 to n,
   something like this sketch:

*fix f n := (if n = 0 then 0 else n + f (n-1))*

Now, let's *not* use structural recursion on n.

Instead, we use well-founded recursion on n,
   using that the relation less-than ('lt') is
   wellfounded.  The function f terminates because
   the recursive call is made on a structurally 
   smaller term  (in the decreasing Acc-chain).
*)

(* First we do it for nat *)

```
Require Import Arith.Arith.
Require Import Program.Utils. (* for 'dec' *)
Require Import Wellfounded.
```

(* From a proof that a relation is wellfounded, 
   we can get a proof that a particular element
   in its domain is accessible.

The Check commands here are not necessary, just for
   documentation, dear reader.
*)

```
Check well_founded : forall A : Type, (A -> A -> Prop) -> Prop.
Check lt_wf : well_founded lt.
Check (lt_wf 4711 : Acc lt 4711).
```

(* First define a 'functional' F for f. It is a function that
   takes a function F_rec for the 'recursive call' as an argument. 
   Because we need to know n <> 0 in the second branch
   we use 'dec' to turn the boolean if-condition into a
   sumbool. This we get info about it into the branches.

We write most of it with refine, and leave some holes 
   to be filled in with tactics later.
*)

```
Definition F (n:nat) (F_rec : (forall y : nat, y < n -> nat)): nat.
  refine ( if dec (n =? 0) then 0 else n + (F_rec (n-1) _ ) ).

  (* now we need to show that n-1 < n, which is true for nat if n<>0 *)
  destruct n; now auto with *.
Defined.
```

(* The functional can be used by an iterator to call f
   as many times as is needed.

Side note: One can either make an iterator that takes the maximal
   recursive depth d as a nat argument, and recurses on d, but
   then one has to provide d, and also a 'default value'
   to return in case d reaches zero and one must terminate
   early.

The neat thing with well-founded recursion is that the
   iterator can recurse on the proof of wellfoundedness
   and doesnt need any other structure or default value
   to guarantee it will terminate.
 *)

(* The type of Acc_iter is pretty hairy *)

```
Check Acc_iter :
      forall (A : Type) (R : A -> A -> Prop) (P : A -> Type),
       (forall x : A, (forall y : A, R y x -> P y) -> P x) -> forall x : A, Acc R x -> P x.
```

(* P is there because the return type could be dependent on the argument,
   but in our case, f:nat->nat, and R = lt, so we have
 *)

```
Check Acc_iter (R:=lt) (fun _:nat=>nat) :
  (forall n : nat, (forall y : nat, y < n -> nat) -> nat) ->
   forall n : nat, Acc lt n -> nat.
```

(* Here the first argument is the functional that the iterator takes,
   the second argument n is the input to f, and the third argument is 
   a proof that n is accessible.
   The iterator returns the value of f applied to n.

Several of Acc_iter's arguments are implicit, and some can be inferred.
   Thus we can define f simply as follows:
*)

```
Definition f n := Acc_iter _ F (lt_wf n).
```

(* It works like a charm *)

```
Compute (f 50). (* This prints 1275 *)
Check eq_refl : f 50 = 1275.
```

(* Now let's do it for Z.  Here we can't use lt,
   or lt_wf because they are for nat.  For Z we
   can use Zle and (Zwf c) which takes a lower bound.
   It needs a lower bound under which we know that the function
   will always terminate to guarantee termination.
   Here we use (Zwf 0) to say that our function will
   always terminate at or below 0.  We also have to
   change the if-statement to 'if n <= 0 then 0 else ...'
   so we return zero for arguments less than zero.
 *)

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Zwf.

Open Scope Z.
```

(* Now we define the function g based on the functional G *)

```
Definition G (n:Z) (G_rec :  (forall y : Z, Zwf 0 y n -> Z)) : Z.
  refine (if dec (n<?0) then 0 else n + (G_rec (n-1) _ )).

  (* now we need to show that n-1 < n *)
  now split; [ apply Z.ltb_ge | apply Z.lt_sub_pos].
Defined.

Definition g n := Acc_iter _ G (Zwf_well_founded 0 n).
```

(* But now we can't compute! *)

```
Compute (g 1).
```

(* We just get a huge term starting with

```
     = (fix
        Ffix (x : Z)
             (x0 : Acc
                     (fun x0 x1 : Z =>
                      (match x1 with
                       | 0 => Eq
                       | Z.pos _ => Lt
                       | Z.neg _ => Gt
                       end = Gt -> False) /\
                      match x0 with
                      | 0 => match x1 with
                             | 0 => Eq
                             | Z.pos _ => Lt
                             | Z.neg _ => Gt
                             end
                      | Z.pos x2 =>

    ...

 end) 1 (Zwf_well_founded 0 1)
     : (fun _ : Z => Z) 1
   )
```

---

Comment: I noticed that `Zwf_well_founded` is defined as `Opaque` in the library, so I tried to make it `Transparent` by copying the proof and ending the lemma with `Defined.` instead of `Qed.` but that didn't help...

Added observation:

If I define `f'`  for `nat` with `Fixpoint` instead, and recurse on the
accesibility proof, *and end with `Defined.`* then it computes. But if I end with `Qed.` it doesn't reduce.  Is this related?  I guess there is an issue of transparency in the definition of `G` or `g` somewhere... Or am I completely mistaken?

```
Fixpoint f' (n:nat) (H: Acc lt n) : nat.
  refine (if dec (n<=?0) then 0 else n + (f' (n-1) (Acc_inv H _))).
  apply Nat.leb_gt in e.
  apply Nat.sub_lt; auto with *.
Defined.  (* Compute (f' 10 (lt_wf 10)). doesn't evaluate to a nat if ended with Qed. *)
```

Anyway, my problem persists for `Z`.

```
Fixpoint g' (n:Z) (H: Acc (Zwf 0) n) : Z.
  refine (if dec (n<=?0) then 0 else n + (g' (n-1) (Acc_inv H _))).
  split; now apply Z.leb_gt in e; auto with *.
Defined.

Compute (g' 10 (Zwf_well_founded 0 10)).
```

Comment: This is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354286/compute-with-a-recursive-function-defined-by-well-defined-induction).

Comment: This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478445/) is somewhat related as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making [`Zwf_well_founded`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Zwf.html#Zwf_well_founded) transparent won't help, because of the way it is defined in the standard library:

> ```
> Lemma Zwf_well_founded : well_founded (Zwf c).
> ...
>     case (Z.le_gt_cases c y); intro; auto with zarith.
> ...
> Qed.
> ```

If you replace the line in the proof above with

```
     case (Z_le_gt_dec c y); intro; auto with zarith.
```

and replace `Qed.` with `Defined.` (which you already did) everything should work. This is due the fact that the original proof depends on a logical term, and that prevents the evaluator from doing pattern-matching, because logical entity `Z.le_gt_cases` is opaque, while computational entity `Z_le_gt_dec` is transparent. See [Using Coq's evaluation mechanisms in anger](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/coq-eval/) blog post by Xavier Leroy. You might also find useful [Qed Considered Harmful](https://gmalecha.github.io/reflections/2017/qed-considered-harmful) post by Gregory Malecha.

Instead of modifying the proof of `Zwf_well_founded` you can reuse [`Zlt_0_rec`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.ZArith.Wf_Z.html#Zlt_0_rec) like so:

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.

Open Scope Z.

Definition H (x:Z) (H_rec : (forall y : Z, 0 <= y < x -> Z)) (nonneg : 0 <= x) : Z.
  refine (if Z_zerop x then 0 else x + (H_rec (Z.pred x) _ )).
  auto with zarith.
Defined.

Definition h (z : Z) : Z :=
  match Z_lt_le_dec z 0 with left _ => 0 | right pf => (Zlt_0_rec _ H z pf) end.

Check eq_refl : h 100 = 5050.
```

It's a bit less convenient because now we have to deal with negative numbers in `h`.

Comment: It was a pleasure to answer a question showing a great deal of research effort!