# Coq can't compute well-founded defined with Fix, but can if defined with Program Fixpoint

Tags: recursion, coq, totality

As an exercise to understand recursion by a well-founded relation I decided to implement the extended euclidean algorithm.

The extended euclidean algorithm works on integers, so I need some
well-founded relation on integers. I tried to use the relations in `Zwf`, but things didn't worked (I need to see more examples). I decided that would easier to map `Z` to `nat` with the `Z.abs_nat` function and then just use `Nat.lt` as relation. Our friend `wf_inverse_image` comes to help me. So here what I did:

```
Require Import ZArith Coq.ZArith.Znumtheory.
Require Import Wellfounded.

Definition fabs := (fun x => Z.abs_nat (Z.abs x)). (* (Z.abs x) is a involutive nice guy to help me in the future *) 
Definition myR (x y : Z) := (fabs x < fabs y)%nat.
Definition lt_wf_on_Z := (wf_inverse_image Z nat lt fabs) lt_wf.
```

The extended euclidean algorithm goes like this:

```
Definition euclids_type (a : Z) := forall b : Z, Z * Z * Z.

Definition euclids_rec : (forall x : Z, (forall y : Z,(myR y x) -> euclids_type y) -> euclids_type x).
  unfold myR, fabs.
  refine (fun a rec b => if (Z_eq_dec a 0) then (b, 0, 1)
                      else let '(g, s, t) :=  rec (b mod a ) _ a 
                           in (g, t - (b / a) * s, s)
                      ).
apply Zabs_nat_lt. split. apply Z.abs_nonneg. apply Z.mod_bound_abs. assumption.
Defined.

Definition euclids := Fix lt_wf_on_Z _ euclids_rec.
```

Now let's see if it works:

```
Compute (euclids 240 46). (* Computation takes a long time and results in a huge term *)
```

I know that can happen if some definition is opaque, however all my definitions end with `Defined.`. Okey, something else is opaque, but what?
If is a library definition, then I don't think that would cool to just redefine it in my code.

It seems that my problem is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186751/coq-cant-compute-a-well-founded-function-on-z-but-it-works-on-nat), [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354286/compute-with-a-recursive-function-defined-by-well-defined-induction) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478445/eval-compute-is-incomplete-when-own-decidability-is-used-in-coq).

I decided to give `Program Fixpoint` a try, since I never used it. I was surprised to see that I could just copy and paste my program.

```
Program Fixpoint euclids' (a b: Z) {measure (Z.abs_nat (Z.abs a))} : Z * Z * Z :=
  if Z.eq_dec a 0 then (b, 0, 1)
  else let '(g, s, t) := euclids' (b mod a) a in
       (g, t - (b / a) * s, s).
Next Obligation.
apply Zabs_nat_lt. split. apply Z.abs_nonneg. apply Z.mod_bound_abs. assumption. 
Defined.
```

And even more surprise to see that works just fine:

```
Compute (euclids' 240 46). (* fast computation gives me (2, -9, 47): Z * Z * Z *)
```

What is opaque in `euclids` that is not in `euclids'` ?
And how to make `euclids` work?

Comment: `Program Fixpoint` uses `Wf.Fix_sub` (where you use `Fix`) which uses a computational value to determine recursion, `(forall y : {y | myR y x}, euclids_type (proj1_sig y))` instead of `(forall y : Z,(myR y x) -> euclids_type y)`.  That could perhaps have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Okey, something else is opaque, but what?

`wf_inverse_image` is opaque and so are the lemmas it relies on: `Acc_lemma` and `Acc_inverse_image`. If you make these three transparent `euclids` will compute.

The evidence of well-foundness is basically your parameter you do structural recursion on, so it must be transparent.

> And how to make `euclids` work?

Fortunately, you don't have to roll your own transparent versions of the aforementioned standard definitions as there is `well_founded_ltof` lemma in `Coq.Arith.Wf_nat` which is already transparent so we can reuse it:

```
Lemma lt_wf_on_Z : well_founded myR.
Proof. exact (well_founded_ltof Z fabs). Defined.
```

That's it! After fixing `lt_wf_on_Z` the rest of your code just works.

Comment: How did you manage to see that `wf_inverse_image` is opaque? Just happen you know it or you inspected all my definitions and the definitions they relies on? Just asking if this happens again.

Comment: You can ask Coq like so: `About wf_inverse_image.` (it tells you among the other stuff if the identifier transparent or opaque) or `Print Opaque Dependencies wf_inverse_image.`